# How to pre-provision crawled properties?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provisioning, search-schema

Is it possible to provision crawled properties on SharePoint **without** data ?

Using on premise sharepoint, I used to manipulate `New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty` to prepare crawled properties during solution deployement.

Using SharePOint online, I didn't found equivalent command.

My goal is actually to be able to ship solutions to customers, inlcuding some search pages that relies on schema customization. However, unless content is crawled, I can't create mappings without the crawled properties.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm like 95% sure that this is not possible in SP Online.

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan: I fear you are right.